# Akka: waiting for multiple messages

Tags: scala, akka, wait, actor

Hi akka gurus:) Can you guide me in this one?

What I'm trying to do - Actor A asks Actor B for a message and wait's for one to arrive back. But, somehow Actor B gives back to A not one message, but 4 of them. Actor A `Future` completes properly, but 3 of rest messages are counted as dead letters. Why? Is this right? I mean, Actor A has a proper handler, why the letters are dead then? :-(

> [INFO] [11/22/2013 22:00:38.975] [ForkJoinPool-2-worker-7]
>   [akka://actors/user/a] Got result pong [INFO] [11/22/2013
>   22:00:38.976] [actors-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]
>   [akka://actors/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from
>   Actor[akka://actors/user/b#-759739990] to
>   Actor[akka://actors/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters
>   encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with
>   configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and
>   'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'. 
>   ...Same message 2 more times...

Please take a look at the code.

```
package head_thrash

import akka.actor._
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("actors")

  val a = system.actorOf(Props[A], "a")
  val b = system.actorOf(Props[B], "b")

  a ! "ping"
  system.awaitTermination()
}

class A extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

  def receive = {
    case "ping" => {
      val b = context.actorSelection("../b")
      val future: Future[String] = ask(b, "ping").mapTo[String]
      future.onSuccess {
        case result: String ⇒ {
          log.info("Got result " + result) // <-- got result pong here, that's okay
        }
      }
    }
    case "pong" => {
      log.info("hmmm...")
    }
  }
}

class B extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = {
    case "ping" => {
      sender ! "pong"
      sender ! "pong" // <-- dead letter!
      sender ! "pong" // <-- dead letter!
      sender ! "pong" // <-- dead letter!
    }
  }
}
```

That really confuses me. Now you can ask - hey man, why do you need B to send many messages? Well, that is the part of more complicated case - A asks B for message. B answers. Then A *waits* for another message from B. The tricky part here is *plain* waiting after the Future completes - and I just can't make my mind to get that model fit into Akka basis.

But fow now, how can I get all 4 messages handled correctly, without dead letters? Thanks :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that actor B is not answering to actor A. If we read the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/index.html#akka.pattern.package) of the ask pattern we find that `ask` create a temporary one-off actor for receiving a reply to a message and complete a `scala.concurrent.Future` with it.

This temporary actor does not handle `"pong"` messages at all, he is just waiting for any answer that you are then casting as a Future of String.

If you want to fix this, you have to modify your actor B so that first it answers to the temporary "ask actor" and then sends messages directly to actor A.

```
class B extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = {
    case "ping" => {
      sender ! "pong"  //the sender is the temp ask actor
      val a = context.actorSelection("../a") // get a ref on actor A
      a ! "pong"
      a ! "pong"
      a ! "pong"
    }
  }
}
```

This is not really clean, but now I hope you understand what is going on.

Comment: You can also include `sendAdditionaReplies: ActorRef` in the first message.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find the code easier to write if you don't wait for the message. Actors work best when you don't think of your app in terms of time or sequence of steps. Just have it able to handle the callback. But use ! not ?. If you need to, use become or an FSM to show the two states.

This isn't the question you asked, but it's something you will want to know. Avoiding an imperative style with actors keeps most of these kind of bugs from happening.

Comment: Well, I tend to agree with you. Ask pattern is really hard to maintain. FSM to research, then :-D

Comment: Yeah, ask pattern gets messy fast. I'd see it as a thing only for specific edge cases. Like in testing where you have to block for a response so the test runs right.

It might be that you don't need an FSM. simple actors can just be ready to handle the callback in its normal receive block. If you need it to not do anything else until it receives that callback then use the FSM or become. become is simpler but FSM has more add-ons when they are needed. Such as on-transitions.